# How to use composer for different version of Xampp and php in Windows?

Tags: php, command-line, composer-php

I have different versions of `xampp` installed in my windows 10 pc . Recently i installed `xampp` having `php` version `5.6.x` as i have to work on projects requiring `php` version `>= 5.6`. I also have `composer` installed which currently uses
`php` version `5.4.x` of `xampp` installed before.

My question is how can i make `composer` use this new version php `5.6` when creating and downloading packages which require minimum of php `5.6`. Currently when i try to install packages requiring `5.6` it's giving me error `this package requires php >=5.6 but your PHP version (5.4) does not atisfy that requirement`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4090

Comment: @Yakng did u found any solution ?

Answer (score -2):

I checked the PATH variable and it contains:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ProccessMaker\Php; C:\xampp\php;
```

So... maybe you have another program installed with PHP.